# Structures in prolog

Tags: structure

Suppose I have to define a set of firewall rules.

```
struct rules {
int sourceL;
int sourceU;
int destL;
int destU;
char *proto;
char *action;
} r1,r2;

r1.sourceL=10;
r1.sourceU=20;
r1.destL=30;
r1.destU=40;
r1.proto="tcp";
r1.action="accept";

r2.sourceL=10;
r2.sourceU=10;
r2.destL=30;
r2.destU=30;
r2.proto="tcp";
r2.action="deny";
```

where sourceL and sourceU are the lower and upper bound of the source IP address, same goes for the destination IP address. For example [10,20,30,40,tcp,allow] means that [10,20] is the subnet of the source and [30,40] is the subnet of the destination.

Is the following representation correct?

```
rule(
r1,
sourceL(10),
sourceU(20),
destL(30),
destU(40),
proto(tcp),
action(accept)
).

rule(
r2,
sourceL(10),
sourceU(10),
destL(30),
destU(30),
proto(tcp),
action(deny)
).
```

If not, how do I represent it in prolog?
The rules are static and do not change during run-time. 
Basically I wanted to check for conflicts among the defined rules, for example, if there are two rules [10,20,30,40,tcp,allow] and [10,10,30,30,tcp,deny] this leads to a conflict.
How can I go about comparing different variables of the structures so that I can detect conflicts in the rules?

Comment: You need to provide a more specific use case. It really depends on what you need to do with the rules: are they static, known at compile time? Or are you going to change them while the program is running? How are you going to use the data from these rules? There are too many different, useful ways you can represent tabular data like this.

Comment: All the data is static. They aren't going to be changed during runtime. Basically, there is an upper bound and lower bound for both source and destination (haven't been mentioned in the code above for the sake of simplicity) which denote the range of the source and destination. I have to check whether there are conflicts in the firewall rules.
So if there is a rule [10,20,30,40,tcp,allow] it means that [10,20] is the subnet of the source and [30,40] is the subnet of the destination. Then If I have another [10,10,30,30,tcp,deny] it is a conflict.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the detail you provided in your comment?

Comment: Sure thing. It's updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can avoid the extra name-wrap inside the struct.

I mean... you can write

```
rule(r1, sourceL(10), sourceU(20), destL(30), destU(40), proto(tcp), action(accept)).
```

but I suspect that is enough and simpler

```
rule(r1, 10, 20, 30, 40, tcp, accept).
```

An example of a possible (and highly improvable) clause for check overlaps (for my semplified rules) in the same proto can be

```
detectConflicts(N1, N2) :-
  rule(N1, SL1, SU1, DL1, DU1, PR, _),
  rule(N2, SL2, SU2, DL2, DU2, PR, _),
  N1 @< N2,
  (   (SL1 =< SL2, SL2 =< SU1)
    ; (SL2 =< SL1, SL1 =< SU2)
    ; (DL1 =< DL2, DL2 =< DU1)
    ; (DL2 =< DL1, DL1 =< DU2) ).
```

If your facts are

```
rule(r1, 10, 20, 30, 40, tcp, accept).
rule(r2, 10, 10, 30, 30, tcp, deny).
```

a call to `detectConflicts(N1, N2)` return four times (detect four conflicts) with `N1` unified to `r1` and `N2` unified to `r2`.

Four times because the fact are conflicting 2 times in source ranges and 2 times in dest ranges.